# How do I make a trail behind my character in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm using SpriteKit (with Xcode 6 and Swift) and I have a character on the screen that I move around with on screen joysticks, and I want a little trail to follow behind him. How do I do that?

[image]

How big would my image need to be, and what would it need to look like?
Also what would I use in my code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should take a look at [`SKEmitterNode`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/SKEmitterNode); it will "emit" particles that you can use as your trail. You can design the look and feel of your particles right in Xcode by adding a "SpriteKit Particle File" to your project:

[image: new particle file]

You'd then load the particle file in to a new `SKEmitterNode` like so:

```
let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "CharacterParticle.sks")
```

Then you'll need to set the `SKEmitterNode`'s `targetNode` property to your `SKScene` so that the particles it emits don't move with your character (i.e. they leave a trail):

```
emitter.targetNode = scene
```

Then add your `emitter` to your character's `SKNode`. Lets assume you have an `SKNode` for your character called `character`, in that case the code would simply be:

```
character.addChild(emitter)
```

Typically this sort of thing would be done in your scene's setup method (in Apple's SpriteKit template, it's usually in `didMoveToView`). It could also be done in your character's custom `SKNode` or `SKSpriteNode` class, if you have one. If you put it in `didMoveToView`, it would look something like:

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    // ... any character or other node setup ...

    let emitter = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "CharacterParticle.sks")
    emitter.targetNode = self
    character.addChild(emitter)

    // ... any other setup ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I really appreciate it. "Be sure to make the SKEmitterNode a child of you character's SKNode so that it follows it around, and set the SKEmitterNode's targetNode property to your SKScene so that the particles it emits don't move with your character (i.e. they leave a trail)." I don't know how to do this, though. I'm using swift, by the way.

Comment: Xcode is crashing whenever I make a new SpriteKit Particle file.

Comment: @glassp I edited my answer to try to clarify how you'd add the emitter. Which beta of Xcode6 do you have? Adding a particle file works fine for me in Beta5, and Beta6 was just released about an hour ago (I haven't tried adding a particle file with it yet though).

Comment: I'm using Xcode beta 6, and so is my dad. I tried it on his Mac Mini too.

Comment: @glassp Wow, yep, I just tried it in Beta6 and it crashes for me as well; I can't even open a particle file that already exists in my project. That's frustrating. If you have a copy of Xcode6-Beta5 floating around, try using that instead.

Comment: I'm using Beta5. It still crashes.

Comment: Thanks though, whenever Apple fixes it I'll use this.

Comment: @glassp You can also create an `SKEmitterNode` directly in code without needing a particle file. It just takes a lot longer to get it looking right that way since you have to run the entire app after every little change to see what it looks like. If you're interested in that approach, take a look at the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKEmitterNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013021-CH1-SW62).

Comment: its work for me too.!! but when i change the trail xScale it break on device and work in simulator ! what is the region behind that?

Answer (score 1):

Although SKEmitterNode is a fine option. I would suggest you use a SKSpriteNode instead. The Emitters in Xcode cause a lot of lag when used frequent and in sequence.

The best way to create a trail in my opinion is by preloading a SKTexture when loading up the application. For this I would suggest creating a class like this.

```
class AssetsManager {      
    private init() {};
    static let shared = AssetsManager();
    
    func preloadAssets(with texture: SKTexture) {
    texture.preload {
        print("Sprites preloaded") 
    }
}
```

And than calling it as so in either your AppDelegate or MenuScene:

```
AssetsManager.shared.preloadAssets(with: SKTexture(imageNamed: "yourImage"))
```

Than for the "Creating a trail part":

1. Create a timer

`var timer: Timer!`

2. Start your timer

`timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: self, selector: #selector(ballTrail), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)`

3. Create the ballTrail function

   ```
     @objc func ballTrail() {

         let trail = SKSpriteNode(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "your Image"))
         trail.size = size
         trail.position = player.position
         trail.zPosition = player.positon - 0.1

         addChild(trail)

         trail.run(SKAction.scale(to: .zero, duration: seconds))
         trail.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: seconds)

         DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
             trail.removeFromParent()
         }
     }
   ```

You can fiddle around with the actions and timings you would like to use. Hopefully this will help someone!